# Not picking up a condition in an if statement on a line read from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am reading from a file with `'include iostream'` and other things in it. In my code I am looping through the lines until it finds the `'include iostream'` and once it does it sets a variable. Here is my code:

```
with open('program.r++', 'r') as file:
    for l in file:
        if l == 'include iostream':
            iostream  = True
```

Here is the file:

```
a
ab
abc
include iostream
abc
ab
a
```

And the python version is 3.8.2.
I have used print statements to see `l` and  `str(iostream)` and that gave me no help as to why it is not recognizing the line.

Comment: Each in line will end with a newline character when iterating a file like this — so you'll need to remove it with `l = l.rstrip()` ***or*** perhaps write the conditional like this: `if l.startswith('include iostream'): ...`.

Comment: Wouldn't  ```line.strip()``` Work aswell? (As seen in the answer below)

Comment: Yes it would work but it would also remove any *leading* whitespace — which may or may not be desired (I was only suggesting the simplest thing that would work and not have any other unnecessary side-effects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include iostream` as written has a trailing space.That is why your condition is not matching.

Try `if l.strip() == 'include iostream'`

to remove the trailing space before the comparison.

Comment: It is also possible that `include iostream` might having trailing \n or \r or both characters.

Comment: It's not a trailing space character, it's a trailing newline character.

Comment: @martineau there was also a trailing space character before OP edited his question.

Comment: Perhaps there was, and if so, the `strip()` removed it, too.